# Groupby sum, index vs. column results

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

For the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a','b','b'], 'data':[5,10,100,30]},columns=['group', 'data']) 
print(df)

  group  data
0     a     5
1     a    10
2     b   100
3     b    30
```

When grouping by column, adding and creating a new column, the result is:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].sum() 
print(df)

  group  data  new
0     a     5  NaN
1     a    10  NaN
2     b   100  NaN
3     b    30  NaN
```

However if we reset the df to the original data and move the group column to the index,

```
df.set_index('group', inplace=True)
print(df)

       data
group      
a         5
a        10
b       100
b        30
```

And then group and sum, then we get:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].sum() 
print(df)

       data  new
group           
a         5   15
a        10   15
b       100  130
b        30  130
```

Why does the column group not set the values in the new column but the index grouping does set the values in the new column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better here is use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return Series with same size like original `DataFrame`, so after assign all working correctly:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].transform('sum')
```

---

Because if assign new Series values are align by index values. If index is different, get `NaN`s:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['data'].sum())
group
a     15
b    130
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Different index values - get NaNs:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['data'].sum().index)
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='group')

print (df.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)
```

---

```
df.set_index('group', inplace=True)

print (df.groupby('group')['data'].sum())
group
a     15
b    130
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Index can align, because values matched:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['data'].sum().index)
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object', name='group')

print (df.index)
Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object', name='group')
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting what you want because when using `df.groupby('group')['data'].sum()`, this is returning an aggregated result with `group` as index:

```
group
a     15
b    130
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Where clearly indexes are not aligned.

If you want this to work you'll have to use [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html), which returns a Series with the transformed vales which *has the same axis length as self*:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('group')['data'].transform('sum')

   group  data  new
0     a     5   15
1     a    10   15
2     b   100  130
3     b    30  130
```